# Application setting configuration in Azure App Service

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

When deploying my application using Azure build and deploy pipelines a Web.config file gets generated that defaults the environment to production.  In this case I want that app service to use a appsettings.Development.json.  I did set this in the configuration on Azure with no change.

```
Name = ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT, Value = Development
```

Comment: When you state: 

" I did set this in the configuration on Azure with no change."

Do you mean the changes had no effect and the site was deployed using the production configuration?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

You can add application setting in portal like below pic.

[image]

You webapp will be in development mode.

[image]

[image]

For more details, pls refer to [the official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

**PRIVIOUS**

`CreateDefaultBuilder` provides default configuration,`appsettings.Environment.json` using the JSON configuration provider.

You can read official document first.

[aspnetcore-3.1#default-configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#default-configuration)

And from the source code, we can easily find why we can't read `appsettings.Development.json` file. (Document, [INI configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#ini-configuration-provider))

So after deployed webapp, we cannot modify the configuration so that the application deployed in the webapp can read the ApplicationSettings in ʻappsettings.Development.json`.

Comment: When I do a deployment in Azure no matter what I set it seems that the application defaults to production.  Looking for a way to deploy my application and have the app use development settings.  When the Web.config file get pushed it sets the env to "Production".  I did do some GIT magic and the web.config file is basically static in the repo, I know there has to be a cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: @MichaelAiello I have updated my answer, I hope it can help you.